# How can I avoid the save dialog when downloading a file with python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, download

I am trying to manipulate the Chrome browser using python selenium to download a CSV file from a site.

However, I am having trouble downloading the CSV file because I get a dialog box asking me to specify a folder to save the file.

The relevant part of the code is below.
The download folder is reflected, but the dialog appears.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

prefs = {
    "download.default_directory": download_folder, # specify download folder
    "download.prompt_for_download": False, # disable download confirmation dialog
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    "safebrowsing.enabled": True,
                }
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

s = Service()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=chrome_options)
```

I want to download a CSV file without displaying a dialog in python selenium.

Comment: Firstly, get csv file href using selenium, then send requests to download

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
However, there is no path to the CSV file in the href on the html, and when the Export button is pressed, the site creates the CSV file, which is then downloaded.
This was not displayed before (about a month ago), but recently, due to an upgrade of Chrome, a dialog box confirming the file save location seems to have appeared.

Comment: all you should need is "download.default_directory": download_folder...  make sure the path is set to a folder that exists and has proper permissions or the browser will fallback to default.  (should be an absolute path)  If you don't set any options at all, it should also not prompt you as Chrome's default is to not prompt.